AWS ALB OAuth to Secure Angular and Springboot api Issue in session management
I deployed my Angular application and Spring Boot application in an AWS ECS container and used an EC2 Application Load Balancer (ALB) to expose the internal application. I secured the application using OAuth2, with an access token that expires in 3599 seconds and a refresh token that expires in 90 days. During the initial login, the application successfully authenticated, and the ALB generated and set the AWSELBAuthSessionCookie in the cookie for every request. However, the AWSELBAuthSessionCookie is regenerated every hour. If there is an idle period of one hour and then an action is triggered in the Angular app, it makes multiple HTTP calls simultaneously. The first request succeeds and the response header contains a set-cookie for the regenerated AWSELBAuthSessionCookie, but the subsequent calls fail and redirect to perform an OIDC login, causing a CORS error and a 302 redirect response. This issue prevents my application from functioning properly. How can I handle this issue?
Below is my ALB Configuration
Resources:
  MyALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PublicSubnet2

  AngularTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: /
      Name: angular-targets
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: stickiness.enabled
          Value: true
        - Key: stickiness.type
          Value: lb_cookie
        - Key: stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds
          Value: 14400

  SpringBootTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: /api/health
      Name: springboot-targets
      Port: 8080
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: stickiness.enabled
          Value: true
        - Key: stickiness.type
          Value: lb_cookie
        - Key: stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds
          Value: 14400

  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: authenticate-oidc
          AuthenticateOidcConfig:
            Issuer: https://your-oidc-provider.com
            AuthorizationEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/authorize
            TokenEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/token
            UserInfoEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/userinfo
            ClientId: your-client-id
            ClientSecret: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:YourSecretId:SecretString:ClientSecret}}'
            SessionCookieName: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie
            SessionTimeout: 14400
            Scope: openid
            OnUnauthenticatedRequest: authenticate
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref AngularTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyALB
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref MyCertificateArn

  APIRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: authenticate-oidc
          AuthenticateOidcConfig:
            Issuer: https://your-oidc-provider.com
            AuthorizationEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/authorize
            TokenEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/token
            UserInfoEndpoint: https://your-oidc-provider.com/userinfo
            ClientId: your-client-id
            ClientSecret: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:YourSecretId:SecretString:ClientSecret}}'
            SessionCookieName: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie
            SessionTimeout: 14400
            Scope: openid
            OnUnauthenticatedRequest: authenticate
          Order: 1
        - Type: forward
          Order: 2
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref SpringBootTargetGroup
            TargetGroupStickinessConfig:
              Enabled: true
              DurationSeconds: 14400
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          Values: 
            - /api/*
      ListenerArn: !Ref ALBListener
      Priority: 1


